# Docker Postgres data volume on the host

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

I've a simple tiny issue. I have an app (ASPNET Core) and db (Postgres). I run the container of the db first and then run the app container so that the app can discover the db at runtime. Now I can connect the Postgres database using pgAdmin tool (On Windows) and everything works fine.

Now if I run the Postgres container with a data volume command like:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d -v pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --network=isolated_network --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=5432 postgres
```

Here, I can connect to Postgres instance running in the container and I get my data there. Here I have the question that where the data volume `pg-data` is available on the host?

Moreover, if I mount my Windows directories to the Docker Engine and run the command:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d -v d:/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --network=isolated_network --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=5432 postgres
```

I do see the `data` folder on in the `D:\` drive but I can't connect to this instance of the Postgres container with pgAdmin tool and my app stops working.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In linux default location of volume is:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes
```

For windows i am not sure. but you can inspect container that will give you path and all details that you want.

```
docker inspect containername
```

Comment: I tried to inspect the volume but I don't get the path on the host.